# Cannot iterate over List in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am getting an error when trying to display objects from a List in my controller.  I am using the Spring Boot Framework.

Here is the error :

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'description' cannot be found on null
```

I am using Spring Boot 2.3.4.  below is the dependency in the maven pom.xml file :

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Here is my thymeleaf html view :

```
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="proj : ${projectList}">
        <td th:text="${proj.name}"/>
        <td th:text="${proj.stage}"/>
        <td th:text="${project.description}"/>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My Project @Entity works just fine :

```
@Entity
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int projectID;
    private String name;
    private String stage; //incomplete, not started, in progress
    private String description;
    ...
}
```

And here is the controller that is taking my Project data and attempting to add it to the model.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    iProjectRepo projRepo;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showHome(Model model) {
        List<Project> projects = projRepo.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("projectList",projects);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

The findAll() is returning a List instead of an Iterable because I changed it in the ProjectRepository extending CrudRepository

```
@Repository
public interface iProjectRepo extends CrudRepository<Project,Integer> {

    @Override
    List<Project> findAll();  //the findAll() by default returns an Iterable.  we override it and change the return type to be a list.
}
```

And finally, here is my project structure :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
th:text="${project.description}"/>
```

To

```
th:text="${proj.description}"/>
```

Comment: Well isn't that something else!  That was the issue. lol.  So much time spent, for such a silly mistake!

Comment: thanks so much @Alien !

Comment: You're welcome... please mark the answer as accepted solution.